# Windows 7 Hide Labels of certain programs

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar

Is there a way to hide labels on some taskbar icons, while leaving the labels for other icons?

I'm currently using the solution to "Hide taskbar labels without combining", but when I have multiple Excel sheets open I have no label to tell me which Excel sheet is which.

I want a way to hide labels on most programs, while leaving the labels on some programs.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [7 Taskbar Tweaker v3.3.1](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) application, you can use the option to only show labels for the active selected application. When Excel has focus, it shows all labels. However when in internet explorer, it will combine the excel labels.

Enable these settings:

- Combine grouped items
- Decombine: Active Group, and show labels

And make sure the windows taskbar settings hides the labels by default.

Comment: If you also go to the "Taskbar Inspector" in 7TT, and right click an application ID, you can choose to always hide labels.